# Auto- Drag and Drop 7z File to be added to self extracting zip, custom config.txt

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, 7zip, self-extracting

I am creating a program that will allow its users to drag and drop a 7z file into it. After that it will then use the "custom" 7zS.sfx and config.txt files embedded within the app to create the self extracting zip. So far I have created the custom config and sfx files for what I need. Now I am creating the application. Could someone please let me know firstly how to add the two files config.txt and 7zS.sfx to the project and used afterwards. NB These files will never change, only the 7z folder will change which is why it stays out of the application.

I am using visual basic for this just to keep it simple. Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: I see you are using VS. are you sure you are using VBA and not VB.Net. VBA (the tag you are using) is meant for MS office

Comment: Sorry changed that now.